# Cloud functions: Delete file from storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a trigger function, when triggered, it will delete a file from storage with a certain name. Problem is here, I do not know the extension of the file. It could be either .png or .jpeg. I tried to write some code to delete the image without regard to file extension, but It does not work. It throws `No such object` error.

```
exports.onUserDeletion = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {

    const userid = user.uid
    const filePath = `user_photo/${userid}.{extension}`
    const file = bucket.file(filePath)

    return file.delete()
})
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or any workaround where I perfom this deletion without knowing the extension in beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Just try both extensions.
2. Store the name in a database ahead of time so you know it for sure later on.